# How to make discord bot randomly skip a response

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This might sound like a weird one but I was wondering how to make a discord bot randomly skip a response when a person says one of the keywords that bot will respond to? I was thinking adding `NULL` to the array would work but it does. Adding `skip()` doesn't seem to work either. I'm just not sure how to do this. Thanks for all the help in advance.

```
var array = ['test', 'test2']; 

const messages = ['what kind of test?', NULL]; 

client.on('message', function(message) {
    if (array.includes(message.content)) {
        setTimeout(function(){message.channel.send(messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)]);}, 3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Javascript is not Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something simple like using `Math.random()` with a variable that you can adjust based on your desired response rate.

`Math.random` will return a pseudo-random number between 0 and less than 1. Whenever the random number is greater than your response rate you can use `return` to exit the function. This isn't the most precise way to guarantee the exact response rate specified but it should be good enough for something like this.

```
const matches = ['test', 'test2'];
const messages = ['what kind of test?', 'Some other response']; 
const responseRate = 0.7;

client.on('message', function(message) {
    if (matches.includes(message.content)) {
         if(Math.random() > responseRate) return;
         setTimeout(function(){message.channel.send(messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)]);}, 3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah yes, this works nicely. I can do a lot with this. Thank you!!